# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to train my model on the imdb movie review dataset to extract sentiment out of text.

Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
imdb, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

train_data, test_data = imdb['train'], imdb['test']

training_sentences = []
training_labels = []

testing_sentences = []
testing_labels = []

for s,l in train_data:
    training_sentences.append(str(s.numpy()))
    training_labels.append(str(l.numpy()))
for s,l in test_data:
    testing_sentences.append(str(s.numpy()))
    testing_labels.append(str(l.numpy()))

training_labels_final = np.array(training_labels)
testing_labels_final = np.array(testing_labels)


vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 120
trunc_type = 'post'
oov_tok = '<OOV>'

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token = oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences)
padded = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen=max_length, truncating=trunc_type)

testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, maxlen=max_length, truncating=trunc_type)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But when I fit the model with this code:

```
num_epochs=10
model.fit(padded, training_labels_final, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(testing_padded, testing_labels_final))
```

this error pops up:

> UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported    [[node Cast (defined at >>ipython-input-12-7ee16367fdd2>:2) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_302373]
> Function call stack: train_function

I don't know how to move forward I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I was mistakenly trying to convert the float label tensors(0&1) to string. I just had to remove that and it worked.